# Search log dataset

Tags: search-engine, recommendation-engine

I'm interested in training a query recommendation system on top of search queries but it looks like such data is not made available. Are there some research centers or industry labs that have compiled corpora of search-engine queries?
Is there any search log that belong to search engines like google,yahoo,bing?

Tnx

Comment: This question ranks highly in the google results for "search log data set", so if you ever found one you should answer your own question :)